# Chrome asks to save password without form submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, pjax

There is a `Profile` page that allows the user to edit his personal details like Name, Email, Password etc.

[image]

When I enter some value in the password field while I am on the page, and then navigate to another page via **`pjax` without submitting the form**, Chrome asks to save password.

I tried setting the value of the password field to empty string by
`$('#user_password').val("");`
 
when the user clicks on a **`pjax`** link
but Chrome still displays the same prompt.

What could be the possible reasons for this to happen? How do I disallow this to happen?

The application is build on `Rails 3.0.20`

**EDIT:**

I tried resetting `autocomplete` which was `on`. Turning it `off` does not change the behaviour.

The prompt to save password appears **only when moving to another *pjax* page**. There is no prompt in standard redirections. I assume it is because `pjax` submits the entire page which the browser interprets as a form submit but cannot prevent that from happening.

Comment: Do you have autocomplete off? Are you using any auto fill plugins?

Comment: No and No. I do not have autocomplete off and am not using any auto fill plugin.

Comment: ... Well, at the very least you should turn autocomplete off; different browsers seem to handle it different ways.

Comment: @DaveNewton Was using a shared partial, which had autocomplete enabled. Setting it to off does not appear to have made any difference in the behaviour. Could it be something that `pjax` does? Perhaps it submits the entire page and Chrome interprets it as a form submit?